# Shorter way to strip all html, add shortcode, preg_repace

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace, strip

This works perfectly for what I'm using it for (auto meta description and og:description content for WordPress), but I wonder if there is a way to write it shorter/cleaner:

```
    $content = $post -> post_content;
    $content = wp_trim_words($content, 40, '...'); // 40 words
    $content = trim(str_replace('&nbsp;','',$content));
    $content = do_shortcode($content);   
    $content = html_entity_decode($content); 
    $content = strip_tags($content);    
    $content = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $content);
```

### Updated

Okay, I think this will do the trick. I wanted to be able to use it again and again and then I thought, hey maybe it's like js. I'm a visual designer in my brain so it takes me sometime to get the hang of this stuff.

```
function do_meta_description_cab() {
        global $post;
        $content = $post -> post_content;
        $content = wp_trim_words($content, 40, '...'); // 40 words
        $content = trim(str_replace('&nbsp;','',$content));
        $content = do_shortcode($content);   
        $content = html_entity_decode($content); 
        $content = strip_tags($content);    
        $content = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $content);

        return $content;

}

//Usage: $content = do_meta_description_cab();
```

Comment: What is `shortcode` and `wp_trim_words`; wordpress functions?

Comment: Yes, but I could probably use just php here.

Comment: So are you just looking to replace the wordpress functions or do you want to do this all in one line/function?

Comment: Well, I think I figured it out. I will update the question in a couple min. after I test it.

Comment: Yep, what I did worked. This will be fine for me. Thank you for your time, I appreciate it.

Comment: Okay, you could probably simplify that trim and strip into your preg_replace. Something like `preg_replace('/(\s\s+/|&nbsp|^\s+|\s+$)/', '', $content);`.

Comment: Thank you for that! I was wondering what the delimiter was to put it all together, reading the manual was killing my brain at that time.

Comment: For WordPress, I had to use a tilde  `$content = preg_replace('~/(\s\s+/|&nbsp|^\s+|\s+$)/~', '', $content);`

Comment: You should get rid of the `/`s in that case.

Answer (score 0):

To strip all html opening and closing tags, you can use :

```
    $content = preg_replace('/<[^>]+>|<\/[^>]+>/', '', $content);
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it. I figured it out and updated my question.